# Which cloud storage (dropbox, googledrive, ?) able to be accessed by multi user without Oauth authentication

Tags: c#, xamarin, google-drive-api, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to create a mobile app (xamarin form, c#) that access a cloud storage to store my files like .csv and images which are read only by users.
I could then update the data/files in the storage, and make it available to all users.
I don't want my users to authenticate by using their account.
I expect that the app know how to connect and access to my account (i.e. my dropbox account or gdrive account) in background. It will be seamless to the user.
In short, I would like make my dropbox or gdrive or other clouds files, able to be seen by all users via my app

I tried dropbox and gdrive, but it seems like they use Oauth which require users to login to their account, I don't want that.

Any recommendation or some insight for me?

Thanks a lot stackoverflow

Comment: Note the google .net client library does not support Xamarin. You will need to code this yourself.   Check out service account authorization.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store user information in the cloud service in any way, [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api) may be the best choice.

The following address describes all the requirements for integrating the application with Google Drive
https://developers.google.com/drive/api
In Google Drive, you will receive an API key through which your application will upload and download files, and you do not need to create an account for the application's uses  or personally authentication.

To use, it is enough to be able to call a rest API
and here it is the API reference:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference